# vba insert existing table to a new table

Tags: sql-server, vba

I am trying to insert table to new table.
This is my code and I am not sure how to proceed.
It is not a complete code.

```
Private Sub CommandSubmit_Click()

Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim strConn As String
Dim par As ADODB.Parameter           'input

strConn = "DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=CHU-AS-0004;DATABASE=RTC_LaplaceD_DEV;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.Open strConn               'open connection

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.CommandText = "dbo.SubmitBlend"
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn

Dim strBlend As String

strBlend = "INSERT INTO dbo.SubmitBlend SELECT * FROM dbo.AddBlendPrac"



cmd.Execute

conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing
Set cmd = Nothing
MsgBox "Request Submit Succeed"
```

I have create a table first, and this table has data. This table needs to be inserted to a new table. Is there any one how to code this one? Any comments would be greatly helpful :)

Comment: Can you explain why do you think this is not working? What do you experience? Is the code crashing, are there such problems?

Comment: `select * into [new] from [old]`

Comment: why do you need to copy from one table to another in your application? This smells like a bad database design. Unless this code is part of a tool specifically for making structural changes to the database, then I would question why you would need this - I would be interested to know the reason. Possibly you can do something better by using relationships between the two tables instead of a complete duplication of the data.

Comment: @ADyson a valid case when such copies are needed is for instance archiving.

Comment: @LajosArpad I would think that's almost certainly done more simply using replication and/or backups

Comment: @ADyson that's simplicity, we have speaken about validness

Comment: Instead select * from  ,  it seems to be described all field names.

Comment: @LajosArpad Just IMHO, but if there's a simpler, cheaper, easier and more reliable way to do something, then the alternative is only barely valid. Validity of a solution is not just about technical possibility, it's also about return on investment. Yes, you could use this type of query in an application for what you're suggesting, but in the vast majority of scenarios it would be very inefficient to develop and use such a tool compared to the readily available and more sophisticated alternatives. It could be what the OP is trying to do, of course, but it seems unlikely.

Comment: @ADyson Management is very important indeed, but I define management as the methodology which solves the task of choosing the most feasible solution from valid options. Something can be valid but not very feasible in the same time. At the point of development, especially when we talk with beginners we need to show them what is valid and show how it is feasible or unfeasible. Anyways, our debate is an exchange of differing opinions. Also, sometimes simplicity is unfeasible. To determine how feasible something is we need detailed information of particularities.

Comment: @LajosArpad true, we are talking largely about semantics. The best solution is always dependent on the precise circumstances. And to go back to the question itself, you're correct we don't know the exact circumstances for which this code is being developed. I just wanted to point out to the OP that, while someone may give a technically correct answer to the stated question, that the fact they want to do this task may be a symptom of an underlying design problem. It's just assumption I made based on my assessment of the probabilities. If OP wants to clarify, we can see if it's correct or not.

Comment: @ADyson I think we reached an agreement, the op will definitely have to review the currently chosen approach.